# Why I need generic in Typescript

Tags: .net, class, typescript, generics

In below sample i use generic function:

```
function Identity<T>(arg: T): T[] {

    return arg;
}
```

I can write my method in this way :

```
  function loggingIdentity(arg) {
          return arg;
    }
```

Both of method can accept any type value and return any value.what is benefit of using generic for above method ?
in other sample i have used generic for create a class:

```
class GenericNumber<T> {
    zeroValue: T;
    add: (x: T, y: T) => T;
}
let myGenericNumber = new GenericNumber<number>();
myGenericNumber.zeroValue = 0;
myGenericNumber.add = function(x, y) { return x + y; };
```

I can create class  and new object without using generic :

```
 class GenericNumber {
        zeroValue;
        add: (x, y);
    }
    let myGenericNumber = new GenericNumber();
    myGenericNumber.zeroValue = 0;
    myGenericNumber.add = function(x, y) { return x + y; };
```

in c# language type determination is mandatory but in typescript is optional and We can declare a property or variable or parameter without type determination and they can be of any type.

I would be happy if anyone describe me importance and all benefit of using  generic in typescript.

Comment: You can use `any` everywhere in TypeScript. But then you're basically using JavaScript, and don't have any type safety anymore, which is the reason why TypeScript exists in the first place. Isn't it nice that the IDE tells you what an array is supposed to contain, and refuses to let you push a string into an Array<number>?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In all your examples, `T` can be any type, but *all `T`s are the same type*. This is important: Let's consider your `GenericNumber` class. It has an `add` method, that takes two arguments of type `T` and returns a `T`. This might be a `add(x:number, y:number):number` or a `add(x:string, y:string):string` - but never a `add(x:string, y:Foo):boolean`.

Also, the typescript compiler will know that if you pass in two `number`s, the function will return a `number` as well. This can be valuable information at the callsite of the function.

I also recommend you read the [chapter on generics in the typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) - the first section "Hello World of Generics" basically answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simple Queue (first in, first out) data structure implementation. A simple one in TypeScript / JavaScript looks like:

```
  class Queue {
                private data = [];
                push = (item) => this.data.push(item);
                pop = () => this.data.shift();
               }
```

One issue with this implementation is that it allows people to add anything to the queue and when they pop it - it can be anything.

```
     class Queue {
       private data = [];
       push = (item) => this.data.push(item);
       pop = () => this.data.shift();
      }

      const queue = new Queue();
      queue.push(0);
      queue.push("1"); // Oops a mistake
```

// a developer walks into a bar'

```
console.log(queue.pop().toPrecision(1));
console.log(queue.pop().toPrecision(1)); // RUNTIME ERROR
```

One solution is to go ahead and create special classes just for these constraints. E.g. a quick and dirty number queue:

```
 class QueueNumber
 {
     private data = [];
     push = (item: number) => this.data.push(item);
     pop = (): number => this.data.shift();
  }

          const queue = new QueueNumber();
          queue.push(0);
          queue.push("1"); // ERROR : cannot push a string. Only numbers allowed.
```

What you really want is a way to say that whatever the type is of the stuff getting pushed it should be the same for whatever gets popped. 
This is done easily with a generic parameter (in this case, at the class level):

/** A class definition with a generic parameter */

```
class Queue<T> {
  private data = [];
  push = (item: T) => this.data.push(item);
  pop = (): T => this.data.shift();
}
```

Some ways you can use generics

### 1. Generic Class

Generic class uses type parameters to define a class which will work with different data types.

For example in the following generic class T is the type parameter.

```
class Department<T>
{
    //different types of employees
     private employees:Array<T>=new Array<T>();
     add(employee:T)
     {
    this.employees.push(employee);
     }
}
```

You can define a class which will work with HREmployee type as:

```
let hrDepartment:Department<HREmployee> = new :Department<HREmployee>();
```

### 2. Generic function

Generic function works with different data types by defining generic parameters.In the following example we have declared a Generic function called GenericFunction. The type passed to this function is called T.We are using T to declare the type
of parameters passed to the Generic Function function.We are also using T to declare the return type of the function.

```
function GenericFunction<T>(x:T):T
{
    return x*x;
}
```

You can call the Generic Function by using the following syntax:

```
GenericFunction<int>(1);
```